# Which SLIC version do I have and is it valid?

Tags: windows, license, windows-activation, oem

I have purchased my laptop in 2011. I have some SLIC ACPI table but IIRC FreeDOS was pre‐installed.

I have done hexdump on it. Here is output:

```
0000000 4c53 4349 0024 0000 ac01 4553 4343 4453
0000010 484c 3334 5453 5241 0000 0604 4c20 5054
0000020 0000 0000                              
0000024
```

Is it valid SLIC? If yes, which version? Will Windows activate with it?

Comment: Why do you believe your machine even has a Windows stored in the ACPI table?  If it came with FreeDOS, it very likely, did not come with a Windows license.  We can’t tell anything from the hex dump.

Comment: Why does it have SLIC table?

Comment: *Will Windows activate with it?* We can't answer that. Only Microsoft can tell you that.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, it could be used on VM.

Comment: Huh? What's that have to do with whether we can answer that question?

Comment: @NonameAnonymous - I have no idea.  However, there is other data stored in the ACPI table, other than the Windows license

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, you could install Windows (XP, Vista or 7, I don't know) on a VM, install certificate and product key and then see will it work.

Comment: *You* could since you have the device. **We** can't since we don't have it.

Comment: If the computer came with a Windows license it would be an OEM license, hardware limited to that specific computer, legally speaking.

Answer (score 1):

You have *incomplete* SLIC ACPI table with no version. It only includes vendor name which is Samsung.

This table will only prevent KMS activation of some Windows versions. To activate Windows using OEM:SLP key, you should have correct version of *complete* SLIC table and matching certificate. Samsung SLIC tables are only available for Windows Vista (2.0) and 7 (2.1) which are deprecated operating systems.